# Dart nullable records with pattern matching: The matched value of type '(String, int)?' isn't assignable to the required type '(Object?, Object?)'

Tags: dart, pattern-matching, record, destructuring

Given the following function:

```dart
(String, int)? getPair() {
  return ('hello', 42);
}
```

I can access the multiple returns using the fields like so:

```dart
final pair = getPair();
if (pair != null) {
  String word = pair.$1;
  int number = pair.$2;
}
```

However, I'd prefer to destructure the values using some sort of pattern matching. This is what I tried:

```dart
final (word, number) = getPair();
```

But that gives the following error:

> The matched value of type '(String, int)?' isn't assignable to the required type '(Object?, Object?)'.
> Try changing the required type of the pattern, or the matched value type.

How would I change the required type of the pattern or the matched value?

Related reference:

- [Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/language/records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that destructuring after the `null`-check, like you did manually using `$1` and `$2`:

```dart
final pair = getPair();
if (pair != null) {
  final (word, number) = pair;
  // ...
}
```

You can do a not-`null` *assert* as part of a declaration pattern:

```dart
final ((word, number)!) = getPair();
```

That will throw if the value is `null`.

You cannot do a `null` *check* as part of a declaration, because declaration patterns must be irrefutable, and a check can fail.

You can do the null check as part of a refutable pattern check, using `?`:

```dart
if (getPair() case (final word, final number)?) {
  // ...
} // else { "or else, if needed"; }
```

or

```dart
switch (getPair()) {
  case (final word, final number)?: // ....
  // default: "or else, if needed";
}
```

Since you're then also matching the type in the following destructuring, the `?` can be removed.

Or you can combine the two approaches, if you also want the binding of `pair`:

```dart
if (getPair() case final pair?) { // Bind `pair` if it's not `null`.
  final (word, number) = pair;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pattern match on the result and extract with that:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final (word, number) = switch (getPair()) {
    (String s, int i) => (s, i),
    final v => throw Exception('$v did not match'),
  };
  print('word is $word, number is $number');
}

(String, int)? getPair() {
  return ('hello', 42);
}
```

If you need the vars for a limited scope, you can use if-case:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  if (getPair() case (final String word, final int number)) {
    print('word is $word, number is $number');
  }
}

(String, int)? getPair() {
  return ('hello', 42);
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `switch` and `if-case`. I was hoping there was a one-liner that I was missing but it's good to get your second take. Thank you. I'll take it.

Comment: Ahh, it just occurred to me that the second one might infer the types properly, and it does.  So you can leave "String" and "int" out of the pattern and it still works nicely.

Comment: Sorry to switch the accepted answer after I had already chosen yours. I should have waited a few days. Yours is still great but the new one in more canonical.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a little more verbose that what I was looking for, but this is a partial solution:

```dart
final pair = getPair();
if (pair == null) return; // or throw/break/continue
final (word, number) = pair;
```

I welcome another answer if there is a more direct way to do it.

Comment: Beware those variables are scoped to that if.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, I'd probably use early return in a normal project. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Except that early return means the variables still have limited scope to the function this is declared in.